# SQL. Delete duplicate records based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, categories, sql-delete

I have a `TABLE` called Food with a few thousand records.  Each record is a food consisting of a Description and 5 categories.  Each succeeding category is more specific than the last.  Description, cat1, and cat2 cannot accept `NULL` values.  Cat3, cat4, and cat5 can accept `NULL` values.

For example:

```
description | cat1 | cat2    | cat3  | cat4      | cat5
Green apple | Food | produce | NULL  | apple     | NULL
Root beer   | Bev  | Non-Alc | NULL  | Root beer | NULL
```

The issue I'm having is that there are lots of duplicate descriptions assigned different categories.  And I need help writing a code that can delete these duplicates by certain conditions.

Example:

```
description    | cat1 | cat2     | cat3     | cat4  | cat5
Mango Syrup    | Food | Produce  | NULL     | Mango | NULL
Mango Syrup    | Food | Dry Good | NULL     | NULL  | Syrup
Pepperoni Pizza| Food | Meat     | Pepperoni| NULL  | NULL
Pepperoni Pizza| Food | Bakery   | NULL     | Pizza | NULL
```

I have hundreds of these, and luckily, they're all set up the same way.  Out of the three columns cat3, 4, and 5, only one can be populated.  If a record's cat5 `IS NOT NULL`, cat3 and cat4 will be `NULL`. If a record's cat4 `IS NOT NULL`, cat3 and cat5 will be `NULL`.  If a record's cat3 `IS NOT NULL`, cat4 and cat5 will be `NULL`.

The correct duplicate is the item whose record has the most specific category populated.  All other duplicates should be deleted.

Things I've tried:
`GROUP BY` and using `MIN()` or `MAX()` to aggregate different categories.  This doesn't give me the result I want.

Anything will help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Don't be shy.  Which do you want duplicated?

Comment: Could you have 2 rows where `cat3` has been populated both times, and both `cat4` and `cat5` have the value `NULL`? For the duplicate data, what are you wanting as the end resultset? Are you looking to update the table, or simply have a "clean" result set returned instead

Comment: So the records you want to keep from the example are the second and last, is that correct?

Comment: Seems to me that the biggest issue here is your table is not well normalized.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, that's correct.

Comment: @Larnu, yes, that can happen.  Those aren't a huge concern though.  And either a clean return or an updated table work.

Answer (score 1):

So for each description, you want the row that has the "biggest" category filled.

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by description
                                order by case when cat5 is null then 1
                                              when cat4 is null then 2
                                              when cat3 is null then 3
                                              when cat2 is null then 4
                                              when cat1 is null then 5
                                         end
                                ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you actually want to delete the other rows, then use an updatable CTE:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by description
                                      order by case when cat5 is null then 1
                                                    when cat4 is null then 2
                                                    when cat3 is null then 3
                                                    when cat2 is null then 4
                                                    when cat1 is null then 5
                                               end
                                      ) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```